# Why I am asked if I am a human being each time to be told that it has not been 20 minutes yet?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, captcha

Sometime, I would like to create questions for a few issues.  Since I don't have enough reputation, when I submit the second question, I am told to wait 20 minutes.  The page does not tell up when first the question was posted.  I have to guess it been 20 minutes or not.  Sometime I guess wrong, but I am asked to solve a captcha to be returned to the same page again?

Why not tell the people to wait again first and check if they are a human being only after the 20 minutes is off?

Comment: Does this still happen?

Comment: Does this still happen now?

Comment: I have not asked several question in a row for a while